# SQL/Vertica - joining events with begin and end date on a calendar

Tags: sql, timeline, vertica

**In short**

I have the begin date and end date of several promotions and I would like to join it with a calendar to see on which days a promotion is active.

**What I currently have**

Table 1

```
PromoName  BeginDate   EndDate     PromoType    
Promo1     2016-03-10  2016-03-12  Type1
Promo2     2016-03-11  2016-03-12  Type2
Promo3     2016-03-14  2016-03-15  Type1
```

Table 2

```
Date   
2016-03-09
2016-03-10
2016-03-11
2016-03-12
2016-03-13
etc
```

**What I would like to have**

```
Date        PromoActive  PromoType1Active  PromoType2Active
2016-03-09  0            0                 0
2016-03-10  1            1                 0
2016-03-11  1            1                 1
2016-03-12  1            1                 1
2016-03-13  0            0                 0
2016-03-14  1            1                 0
2016-03-06  1            1                 0
```

Comment: You deleted your previous question and you still continue to not provide **any** SQL?

Comment: I truly do not understand what SQL you would like to see? I am looking for an SQL query (or multiple) which can turn the first two tables into the second, how does it matter what SQL queries I have used so far?

Comment: Because it shows that you've actually *attempted* something instead of looking like you're having someone else [do the work for you](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/65454013.jpg)

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue for over a week and have not made any substantial progress since. Even though I'd love to solve this on my own, or at least show something that indicates that I'm coming close, I haven't succeeded. I have been doing online searches, followed SQL tutorials, asking colleagues, you name it, but it didn't get me any closer to the solution. Since I suspect that the problem is not extremely complex (once you know the trick, it is a piece of cake) I ask my question here.

Comment: Sidenote: first of all, even though the post does slightly come across as 'gimme the code', I tried to format it in this manner instead of a more lengthy one make it easier-to-read (compared to the previous post). And secondly, the Table 1 which is included in the question was not a table readily available, I used multiple queries to get to that result. The only problem is that I do not know the 'last' step to get to my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. No need to use Vertica's advanced Time Series Analytic functions...

Assuming you have:

```
SQL> select * from table1;
 promoname | begindate  |  enddate   | promotype 
-----------+------------+------------+-----------
 Promo1    | 2016-03-10 | 2016-03-12 | Type1
 Promo3    | 2016-03-14 | 2016-03-15 | Type1
 Promo2    | 2016-03-11 | 2016-03-12 | Type2
```

And:

```
SQL> select * from table2 order by sdate;
   sdate    
------------
 2016-03-09
 2016-03-10
 2016-03-11
 2016-03-12
 2016-03-13
 2016-03-14
 2016-03-15
 2016-03-16
```

Then, just a simple SQL like this should work:

```
select 
    sdate, 
    max(case when ( sdate between begindate and enddate ) then 1 else 0 end) as PromoActive,                                                                         
    max(case when ( sdate between begindate and enddate ) and promotype = 'Type1' then 1 else 0 end) as PromoType1Active, 
    max(case when ( sdate between begindate and enddate ) and promotype = 'Type2' then 1 else 0 end) as PromoType2Active
from 
    table1 cross join table2 
group by sdate
order by sdate
;
   sdate    | PromoActive | PromoType1Active | PromoType2Active 
------------+-------------+------------------+------------------
 2016-03-09 |           0 |                0 |                0
 2016-03-10 |           1 |                1 |                0
 2016-03-11 |           1 |                1 |                1
 2016-03-12 |           1 |                1 |                1
 2016-03-13 |           0 |                0 |                0
 2016-03-14 |           1 |                1 |                0
 2016-03-15 |           1 |                1 |                0
 2016-03-16 |           0 |                0 |                0
```

Comment: What if you have 32 different types?

Comment: 32 different case statements

Comment: I mean... the problem here is to transform N different types (in **different rows**) into N **different columns** (Promo1...PromoN). I see the following options: (1) Pivot (not currently available in Vertica), (2) multiple cases (my answer here above) or (3) Vertica's UDx (UDTF to be precise in this case).

Comment: That was my point. It's not feasible to manage such a use case.

Comment: I like the way you transformed my three options into "not feasibile" :-) Jokes apart, using multiple CASE statements is very common in these cases. One could also write a __polymorphic__ or __overloaded__ UDTF able to return a variable number of columns. Just a few lines of code; very easy to implement. SQL will be shorter for sure but I doubt such UDTF (or a Pivot function) will be faster than multiple cases...